# export dataset with a function

Tags: function

I want to create a function to export a dataset in text mode. I have written

```
exportTXT=function(data,data2) {
write.table(data,"c:\\data\\data2") }
exportTXT(OJ,"OJ.txt")
```

No error message but result is c:\data\data2 without the extension
I want the output to be the file OJ.txt.
How to do?

Sincerely,
Mary A. Marion

Comment: When asking a question about code, it is always a good idea to include a tag for the language you're using. While you're making the [edit] to do so, you can remove your signature; we don't use those here. If you want people to know who you are, change your user name from user60393 to your name in your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4379280/user60393), and it will appear in the lower right corner of every post you make here.

Comment: please add language to tag (looks like R)?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming it's R language, what's happening is that you're not actually passing the function arguments into the function. The `"c:\\data\\data2"` is a fixed `string` and therefore not modified by the function argument. Furthermore, you may face issues if you use "\", you should use `"/"` on any platform. A fix would be of the following form:

```
exportTXT=function(data,file_name) {

#modify path using function argument
file_dest = paste("c:/data",file_name,sep="/")

#write to file
write.table(data,file_dest)}

exportTXT(OJ,"OJ.txt")
```

Of course, the above assumes that the file path `c:/data` exists